# Behavior of char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, buffer-overflow

I am really confused about the following:

```
char *list = malloc(sizeof(char));

list[0] = 'a';
list[1] = 'b';
printf("%s\n", list);
```

My expectation was some kind of undefined behavior, because `list` has only memory for 1 char "object".

But the actual output is `ab`. Why can I access `list[1]` when `list` only has allocated memory for one char?

Comment: You shouldn't have any expectation from undefined behavior. Its every act is deceptive.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means anything can happen as far as the Standard is concerned. Something is actually happening so that should meet your expectations. :)

Comment: compiler aligns data segment.I bet to this cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your memory allocation of `sizeof(char)` bytes (*and considering the allocation is success*),

```
  list[1] = 'b';
```

is out-of-bound access, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There can be no *expectation* from a program causing UB. It can do *anything*, absolutely *anything*.

That said,

- `sizeof(char)` is defined (*guranteed*) to be `1` in C standard.
- Check for the success of `malloc()` before using the return value. Otherwise, the first access, `list[0]` itself will invoke UB as you'll end up dereferencing an invalid pointer (*i.e., accessing invalid memory*)
- Passing a pointer to a non-null-terminated `char` array as argument to `%s` also invokes UB.

Comment: ..non-null-terminated...   and all that stuff is wrong

Comment: char b[]="jyumj";
printf("%s",b);       workin

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин so you think `b` is not null-terminated, i'm afraid, you're wrong.

Comment: how about to type non workin ex

Comment: yea it's null-terminated